Error al realizar cambio de contraseña
Tengo un problema a la hora de poder realizar el cambio de contraseña siempre se me queda en el if del password_verify, así ponga la contraseña correcta siempre me da el mismo mjs "Ups Aviso: La contraseña actual es incorrecta". No se si es la lógica del código que esta mala, pero en verdad esto me tiene full estrés.
formulario
<form class=" " action='config_cambiar_contrasena.php' name="frmContacto" method="POST">
    <div class="field-body">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Contraseña Actual</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input is-small" type="password" name="contrasena" autocomplete="off" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w\S{8,}" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Nueva Contraseña</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input is-small" type="password" name="nueva_contrasena"  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w\S{8,}" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Confirmar Nueva Contraseña</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input is-small" type="password" name="verificar_nueva_contrasena" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w\S{8,}" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <br>
    <div class="columns is-mobile is-centered">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button is-link is-small" type="submit" name="cambiar_contrasena">MODIFICAR CONTRASEÑA</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type='hidden' name='id_usuario' value='<?php echo $editar_linea['id_usuario']; ?>'>
</form>

config_cambiar_contrasena.php
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include "../conexion/conexion.php";
 
if (isset($_POST['cambiar_contrasena'])) {
    // Consultar campos vacíos
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
    $nueva_contrasena = $_POST['nueva_contrasena'];
    $verificar_nueva_contrasena = $_POST['verificar_nueva_contrasena'];
    if (empty(trim($contrasena)) || empty(trim($nueva_contrasena)) || empty(trim($verificar_nueva_contrasena))) {
        $_SESSION['errMSG'] = "¡Ups! Aviso: No pueden haber campos vacíos.";
    } else {
        // Consultar la contraseña actual guardada en la base de datos
        $cedula = $_SESSION['cedula'];
        $sql = "SELECT contrasena FROM usuario WHERE cedula = :cedula LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cedula', $cedula, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $contrasena = $row['contrasena'];
            if (password_verify($contrasena, $row['contrasena'])) {
                if ($nueva_contrasena != $verificar_nueva_contrasena) {
                    $_SESSION['errMSG'] = "¡Ups! Las contraseñas no coinciden.";
                } else {
                    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET contrasena = :nueva_contrasena WHERE cedula = :cedula";
                    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':nueva_contrasena', $nueva_contrasena, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':cedula', $cedula, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                        $_SESSION['successMSG'] ="¡ Bien Hecho: Contraseña actualizada con éxito. !";
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION['errMSG'] = "¡Ups! No se pudo cambiar la contraseña.";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['errMSG'] = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña actual es incorrecta. !";
            }
        }
    }
}
header('location: contrasena.php');
exit;
?>


A simple vista veo 2 problemas.
(1) Estás sobreescribiendo la variable $contrasena, que inicialmente traía la contraseña original, por el hash de la base de datos.
(2) Cuando las 3 contraseñas pasan todas las condiciones, entonces guardas en la base de datos la nueva contraseña a secas, sin calcular su hash. Debes cifrar la $nueva_contrasena usando password_hash() antes de guardarla en la base de datos.
// ...
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena']; // <--- [OK]
    $nueva_contrasena = $_POST['nueva_contrasena'];
    $verificar_nueva_contrasena = $_POST['verificar_nueva_contrasena'];
    
    // ...
    
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $contrasena = $row['contrasena']; // <--- [???] Eliminar esta linea
            if (password_verify($contrasena, $row['contrasena'])) {
                if ($nueva_contrasena != $verificar_nueva_contrasena) {
                    $_SESSION['errMSG'] = "¡Ups! Las contraseñas no coinciden.";
                } else {
                    $nueva_contrasena = password_hash($nueva_contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // <-- AGREGAR LINEA
                    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET contrasena = :nueva_contrasena WHERE cedula = :cedula";
// ...

Analizando el segundo problema, ¿Las contraseñas que ya tienes guardadas en la Base de Datos están generadas con password_hash()? Para que password_verify() funcione, esto es mandatorio.
Por otro lado, el hash generado es largo, mínimo 60 caracteres. El campo en la BD para guardar los hash debe ser por lo menos un VARCHAR(100) para evitar truncamiento y corrupción de los hash.

cierto, pero igual sigue el problema

@yoclens encontré otro problema en el código. Recuerda que las contraseñas guardadas en la BD deben haber sido generadas previamente con password_hash para que password_verify las pueda comparar. Hice un ambiente de pruebas con tu código y aplicando los cambios propuestos, me funcionó.

ok voy a intentarlo a ver como me resulta, otra cosita necesito incluir la librería powerhash.php para que me funcione?

Muchas gracias lo implemente y me funciono perfectamente con los cambios que me indicaste.
